# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'c_lass' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, tkinter

Wrote a code and I'm trying to put tkinter to it but I'm having issues. I'm new to using tkinker

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

valid_c_lass = [1,2,3]      

nam=str(input("Please enter full name: "))
grade_amount=float(input("Please enter grade amount: "))
c_lass=int(input("Please enter class: "))

def calculate(*args):
    while c_lass not in valid_c_lass:
        grade = input('Please enter correct grade ')
        break
    else:
        if (grade == '1') or '2' or '3':
            pass
        if c_lass== 1:
            if grade_amount > 50:
                overallgrade= grade_amount* 0.06
            elif grade_amount >= 100:
                overallgrade =grade_amount * 0.07
            else:
                overallgrade=grade_amount * 0.1
        if c_lass == 2:
            if grade_amount < 50 :
                overallgrade= grade_amount * 0.04
            else:
                overallgrade= grade_amount * 0.06
        if c_lass == 3:
                overallgrade= grade_amount* 0.045

        
root = Tk()
root.title("Grade Calculator")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

mainframe['borderwidth'] = 5
mainframe['relief'] = 'sunken'

# Name:
ttk.Label(mainframe, text='Name:').grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=W)
nam = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=30)
nam.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky= W)

# Grade Amount:
ttk.Label(mainframe, text='Gade Amount:').grid(column=0, row=2, sticky= W)
grade_amount = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=30)
grade_amount.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky= W)

# Class:
ttk.Label(mainframe, text='Class').grid(column=0, row=3, sticky= W)
c_lass = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=30)
c_lass.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky= W)

# Calculate
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Calculate", command=calculate).grid(column=3, row=5, sticky= E)
grade.focus()
root.bind("<Return>", calculate)
root.mainloop()
```

The error I got:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<pyshell#33>", line 3, in calculate
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'c_lass' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: I do not get that error when I run your code. Do we have to provide specific inputs to get that error?

Comment: I can't get your error but I get `NameError: name 'grade' is not defined` because first you use name `grade_amount` but later you check  `grade` but it is not created if `c_lass` is in `valid_c_lass`.

Comment: BTW: it has to be `if (grade == '1') or (grade == '2') or (grade == '3'):` or `if grade in ['1', '2', '3']:`

Comment: Where is grade come from? grade.focus()